# Simple chrome extension URL to send/show

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do something simple and somehow it does not work...
I am trying to build a simple chrome extension that when you click on it it is showing the URL  of the TAB in a simple HTML. How can I do it? this is the code:

## manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "MY EXTENSION",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "the DESCRIPTION",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "main.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

## End of manifest.json

## Main.html:

```
   <html>
<head>
    <title>my title</title>
<script src="jquery.json-2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var pageUrl = null;
    var pageTitle = null;
    var Title1 = 'lala';

    window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
    function windowLoaded() {
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;

      });
    }


    function get(){

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        pageUrl = tab.url;
        pageTitle = tab.title;
        $('#bkmk').attr('value',pageUrl);
        $('#title').attr('value',pageTitle);


    });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="get()">
<p id="currentLink">Loading ...</p>
<hr />
<ul id="savedLinks"></ul>

<tr><td align="right">Link (URL): </td><td><input id='bkmk' name='bkmk' type="text" value="" size="50">
<br><span style="color: red;"></span>
</td></tr>

<script>document.write($bkmk)</script>

</body>
</html>
```

=============

and I placed the jquery.json-2.3.min.js file in the same folder..

Anything I do I cannot make the HTML to show the URL..

Thanks!!

Elikd

Comment: Please include any errors you are seeing in the console, if any.  Also please indicate where the variable `$bkmk` is defined (used in `document.write($bkmk)`).

Answer (score 1):

It appers that you are using jQuery... but you don't have the jQuery library included in a `<script src="..."></script>` block anywhere.  If you're using a local copy of jQuery, you need to include the jQuery library file in your extension directory and refer to its relative path in the extension relative to the HTML page (e.g., `"jquery.min.js"` if it's in the same folder or `"lib/jquery.min.js"` if it's in a folder called `lib`).

In the future, you can get a JavaScript console (with a list of errors) by right-clicking your browser action icon and selecting "Inspect popup".  See Google's [tutorial on debugging Chrome extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I added it but I still cant see the URL. I think something is wrong with the section that get the tab URL.. anywhere I trying to get the URL i cannot see it.